# How to initiate chromedriver, when running Flutter Integration Tests on Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci

I currently have a project, where Flutter Integration Tests are required to be run on a GitLab pipeline. I initiate the download/install of Chrome and ChromeDriver via `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, which appears to work successfully. I then try and start ChromeDriver with `chromedriver --port=4444` before running my first test. The error received is:

```
> $ chromedriver --port=4444 /bin/bash: line 266: chromedriver: command
> not found
```

How do I initiate ChromeDriver in this scenario?

```
# Code to start chromedriver
.webapp:test: &webapp_test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/flutter:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq
    - cd $APP_DIR
    - cd /chromedriver/
    - chromedriver --port=4444
```

FYI, code to install Chrome and ChromeDriver:

```
webapp:test:
  extends: .webapp:test
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    # Chrome and ChromeDriver dependencies
    - cd $APP_DIR
    - apt-get install -y wget unzip
    - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    # Update the package list
    - apt-get update -y
    # Download and Install chrome
    - wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb && rm /tmp/chrome.deb
    # Download and install Chromedriver
    - mkdir /chromedriver
    - wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip"
    - unzip /chromedriver/chromedriver* -d chromedriver
```

Thanks, I am new to this as you can probably tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you want to run the following script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://www.example.com')

print(driver.page_source)
```

The GitLab CI setup could be something like this:

```
chrome:
  image: python:3.11.4
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip
    # Chrome
    - wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - ln -s /opt/google/chrome/chrome /usr/local/bin/
    # Chromedriver
    - wget -q https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
    - unzip -j chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver
    - rm chromedriver-linux64.zip
    - mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
    - chrome --version
    - chromedriver --version
    - pip3 install selenium
  script:
    - python3 run.py
```

Script runs and dumps contents of http://www.example.com.

[image]

You can find more details in [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/chromedriver-in-gitlab-ci-pipeline/), which I have updated to address precisely this question.

Comment: Thanks @datawookie.  Once Chrome and Chromedriver are installed, I am trying to start Chromedriver with '- chromedriver --port=4444' in the GitLab pipeline from within the ymp file.  I have gotten further, and Chromerdriver starts, however no further steps are started, as it seems the running Chromdriver prevents further steps while it is running.  Do you know a way to get following steps to run?  This is assuming that I do need to start Chromerdriver.  Perhaps I need to initiate Chromedriver via a script instead?

Comment: Depends on what you're wanting to do next. Presumably web scraping? Are you going to use Selenium?

Comment: And, yes, the behaviour you are seeing is precisely what's expected. If you run `chromedriver` in your local terminal you'll see that it runs in the foreground and you can't run any further commands in that terminal until you stop it. Depending on what you want to do next, the best approach is (as you mention) to kick off ChromeDriver via a script.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed solution which includes a script that launches Chrome.

Comment: Thank you @datawookie .  I have also updated the script to use '- chromedriver --port=4444 &', which appears to start chromedriver as a background process.  I am attempting to run flutter integration tests, so won't use Selenium (if I am understanding how this is supposed to work!)